# MS Project 10 & 13 - Creating Custom Gantt Chart for Resource Allocation

Tags: charts, microsoft-project, project-management, microsoft-project-2010, gantt

I have created a very basic setup to better monitor staffing and scheduling decisions for my firm. Essentially, I create one task for each new project and assign the resources that will work on that project to the task. All resources will likely be assigned to multiple tasks at the same time as is the nature of the industry. I don't need to enter any subtasks as I am only interested in seeing what resources have already been allocated and for what duration.

The resource usage view gives me a very detailed table with all of the information I am looking for; however, what I would like to see is more of a snapshot view. Ideally, I want the table from resource usage with the accompanying team planner layout. This way others can quickly see if a resource is over/under allocated without having to analyze all of the accompanying data.

I was able to view something similar to what I need with the split Resource Usage/Details: Gantt Chart view, however this shows only one employee's tasks in Gantt chart view at a time and I need to see everyone's.

Any help would be great; I have been stuck on this for weeks now!